# Prevent page refresh in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in my aspx file:

```
<button type="button" id="btnAskQuestion" runat="server" onserverclick="btnAskQuestion_Click">Ask Question</button>
```

I've tried every combination of `onclick="return false;"` and `onclick="preventDefault()"` I can think of, including putting them in the javascript function that gets called. Everything I try has one of two results: either I get a postback, or the server side code (btnAskQuestion_Click) never executes.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to execute a server-side code without a postback?

Comment: I may be phrasing this badly; I just don't want the whole page to refresh. The server side code that's being called updates a variable.

Comment: please see my answer below, most likely you will have to use either AJAX call or UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot execute server-side code this way, using `onserverclick` causes postback.

If you wish to prevent full page refresh and still execute server-side code, you have to call a client-side JS function via `onclick` and execute an AJAX call from there.

Another alternative is to use your button as a trigger for UpdatePanel - this way only partial postback will be performed.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the property `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` in the button markup.

or you can use a "trick" :

Markup

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<div style="display:none">
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnButton" .../>
</div>
```

js

```
function myFunction()
{
  if (true statement)
    $("[id$=btnButton]").click();
  else
    alert("false");
}
```

What this does is that you handle stuff with normal markup and do the logic using js. And you can trigger a click of the button that do something in the server.

Comment: Yeap. Put that on the markup and do what you were thinking to do with js.

Comment: your first suggestion is perfect for this case the second trick is not required. This property is designed for this senario I think. To make the default behavior disabled which is form submit and use the __doPostBack() mechanism and provide any custom functionality. Just have a little bit more understanding of the framework ..

Answer (score 2):

There're **OnClick**, that fires on server and **OnClientClick** that fires on client browser. You should do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAskQuestion" runat="server" 
            OnClick="btnAskQuestion_Click" 
            OnClientClick="return myfunction();">Ask Question</asp:button>
```

If myFunction returns true, then you will have a postback to the server.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is appropriate only for `ASP:Button`, not the button control you are working with.  Given the choice, I'd switch to `ASP:Button`.

You're looking for [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx).  If you put your JavaScript code there, it will kill the PostBack before it can hit the server.

On the other hand, if you're looking to execute server code without a PostBack, that's impossible.  The PostBack is what triggers the server to act.

Comment: HtmlButton doesn't have `OnClientClick`

Comment: Wow, whoops, completely missed that.