# How to Stop Page refresh when button is clicked in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I have an asp button that looks like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnsave" Text="SAVE" AutoPostBack="true"  OnClientClick="return false;"  OnClick="btnsave_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info" />
```

and also using UpdatePanel

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelPurchaseOrder" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsave" />  
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
   </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I Have a Javascript function that is use for open popup Click on Button(Generate Button Event)The Problem is when Fire the Button Event again reload the page But i do not need to page reload when go inside button_click event

Button (for open popup)

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="javascript: return iframeopen('MedicationOrder.aspx'); " ID="MedicationsOrder" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"
                                    Text="Template" />
```

Javascript Function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function iframeopen(pagename) {
                    debugger;
                    if (pagename == 'MedicationOrder.aspx')
                    {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    $('#iframe_reg').attr('src', pagename);
                    document.getElementById("jst").value = "1";
                    $("[id*='btnsave']").click();
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: you can take html button control and write onclick event

Comment: This may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603115/prevent-page-refresh-in-asp-net.

Have you tried an AJAX workaround ?

Comment: @MandarDhadve ya actually i try html button with onserverclick but its same as

Comment: try this <button onclick=iframeopen('MedicationOrder.aspx'); return false value="Template">

Comment: Add your button inside update panel and add Asynchronous postback trriger for button. This will make partial postback for page.